# get dynamic table value on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to get specific **td** value of a **dynamic  table** when **button id='btn1'** is clicked. The **td** value will be displayed in **Display()** which is a modal form.

here's my code for table row:

```html
$query = "SELECT SID , FNAME , MNAME , LNAME , SCONTACT , MOTHER_FNAME , MOTHER_MNAME , MOTHER_LNAME , MCONTACT FROM student"; $result = mysqli_query($db, $query); $result_check = mysqli_num_rows($result); if($result_check > 0){ while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{ echo "
<tr class='tr'>
  <td class='nr'>" . $row["SID"] . "</td>"; echo "
  <td>" . $row["FNAME"] ."&nbsp;". $row["MNAME"] ."&nbsp;". $row["LNAME"] . "</td>"; echo "
  <td>" . $row["SCONTACT"] . "</td>"; echo "
  <td>" . $row["MOTHER_FNAME"] ."&nbsp;". $row["MOTHER_MNAME"] ."&nbsp;". $row["MOTHER_LNAME"] . "</td>"; echo "
  <td>" . $row["MCONTACT"] . "</td>"; echo "
  <td>" . "<button id='btn1' onclick='Display()' class='inline'>Create Offense</button>"; } }
echo "</td></tr>";
```

Code for  getting specific td value:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    var num = $(this).parents("tr").find(".nr").text();
    $(".resultas").text(num);
  });
</script>
```

all I get is the first row td value. Any tips?

Comment: here same button id for all the rows.means duplicated the button id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the same id for each element,so use `class` instead of `id`,change `#btn1` to `.inline`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".inline").click(function() {
    var num = $(this).parents("tr").find(".nr").text();
    $(".resultas").text(num);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
$("#btn1").click(function() {
  
    // change the number in bracket to get specific column value | td:eq(1)
    var num = $(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(1)").text();
    alert(num);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">

  <tr>

    <td>111</td>
    <td>211</td>
    <td>311</td>
    <td><button id='btn1' class='inline'>Create Offense</button></td>

  </tr>

</table>
```